# Integrating a map view into Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, google-maps-api-3, android-maps, cordova-plugins

I would like to integrate a Map view in my Cordova app. I did some research, but wasn't able to answer the following question:

Is there a way to integrate the handset OS system map (is there such a thing?) into a cordova app? Or is the only way to integrate Google Maps via the JS api?

Any hints or code samples are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use a native map with a plugin, [like this one](https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin), or a JavaScript map, [like one shown here](http://blogs.telerik.com/appbuilder/posts/13-12-12/mobile-friendly-mapping-options-for-phonegap-cordova-apps).